# How can I add an editable static section to Shopify?

Tags: e-commerce, shopify, liquid

I’ve been playing around with Shopify’s sections feature. I thought I’d start simple, with a two field static section, to let admins edit the content of a help modal.

I read all the documentation I could find (not a whole lot), and “borrowed” some code from the Debut theme’s header section.

I have created a section file called help.liquid, and called it on my home page using `{% section ‘help’ %}`

The content is outputting on the page as expected, and the Help section is visible in the Sections tab of the admin system, but is uneducable. There must be something I’m missing, but I can’t work out what it is!

The code in my section file is as follows:

```
<div data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="help-section">

    <div class="modal modal--help">
        <div class="modal__hd">
            <h2 class="modal__title">{{ section.settings.help_title }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal__bd">
            {{ section.settings.help_content }}
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Help",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "help_title",
        "label": "Help title",
        "default": "Help"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "help_content",
        "label": "Help content",
        "default": "Here's some info on getting help"
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by «uneducable»? What happens/ does not work ?

Comment: @AliceGirard Sorry, looks like that's an autocorrect - I meant uneditable! The Help section shows up under Sections, but appears grayed out - clicking on it should allow me to edit the two content fields, but actually does nothing

Comment: Did you add this in your sections folder? I'm asking since I don't see why this should not work. I even tested in case there was an issues that I don't see in the schema, but it loads OK on my development shop, so it's not a coding issues.

Comment: @drip, Yes - I've added a file in my sections folder called `help.liquid`

Comment: Check your syntaxis here: `{% section ‘help’ %}` there might be an issue with your quotation marks. Use double quotes, if you are using the start/end quotes it might be an issue.